# Ruby-processing on Android

Tags: android, ruby, jruby, processing

Simple question, obscure answer: **Would it be possible to run [ruby-processing](https://github.com/jashkenas/ruby-processing)** ( a port of [Processing](http://processing.org) which runs on Jruby which runs on Java VM) **on the Android OS**. Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [ruboto-processing](https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto-processing) but I don't know if it is mature yet. At least now we know it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

i saw a video about it in confreaks by sarah allen

http://confreaks.net/videos/15-mwrc2010-mobile-ruby

here is the video & they are running IRB on an android emulator
http://www.confreaks.net/videos/180-rubyconf2009-jruby-everywhere

hope this helps

Comment: Good one but this is all about [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/products/rhodes/) which is a framework that is built into multiple apps, one for each platform. No signs of actual Ruby or JRuby running on Android

Comment: i see , let me check other videos , i thought i saw them running Jruby on an emulator , i'm not sure

Comment: i found the demo where they run the IRB on Android , i didnt see the ruby processing though , here is the video http://www.confreaks.net/videos/180-rubyconf2009-jruby-everywhere

Comment: Good one, why don't you edit your answer to put that link in as well. Will be good for other people searching for similar stuff.